# Using if_else in combination with data.table .SD

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I need to create new columns in a `data.table` based on criteria set relative to some of the existing columns. I encountered some problems with missing data, however. Specifically, for *each* person a few datapoints are missing. For some individuals though the entire data of a questionnaire is missing (see column `p` == 3 or 4 in example data below). In such cases (= entire data of a questionnaire missing) I would like `data.table` to enter `NA` in the output for this particular person. I have tried resolving this using `if_else` from the `dplyr`package. However, `data.table` returns `NaN or 0` *instead of* `NA`as a result even when *all* data of a person is missing (i.e. when column `p` is 3 or 4).

This is my current script, which only *partially* produces the desired output (i.e. correct output for `p`== 1 or 2, but *not* for `p`== 3 or 4).

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# Create example datatable
set.seed(4)
p <- c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5))
time1 <- as.integer(c(sample(1:20, 5, replace=TRUE), sample(21:40, 5, replace=TRUE), rep("NA",10)))
closeness1 <- as.integer(c(NA, NA, sample(c(1:40,NA), 7, replace=TRUE), NA, rep("NA",10)))

dt <- data.table::data.table(p, time1, closeness1)

# Compute new columns
dt[, c("mean1", "sum1") := .( 
  dplyr::if_else(sum(is.na(.SD[time1,]))==length(.SD[time1,]) | sum(is.na(.SD[closeness1,]))==length(.SD[closeness1,]),
                                              as.numeric(NA), .SD[time1 <= 10, mean(closeness1, na.rm=TRUE)]),
  dplyr::if_else(sum(is.na(.SD[time1,]))==length(.SD[time1,]) | sum(is.na(.SD[closeness1,]))==length(.SD[closeness1,]),
                 as.integer(NA), .SD[time1 <= 10, sum(closeness1, na.rm=TRUE)])),
   by = p, .SDcols = c("time1", "closeness1")]
```

The following script produces the output I would want to see. However, this is obviously just for illustrative purposes and I would need to know how to modify the above script to produce the desired outcome:

```
# Select rows from original data that were as intended
p12 <- dplyr::filter(dt, p %in% c(1,2))

# Create new data.table with corrected output
p <- c(rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5))
time1 <- as.integer(rep("NA",10))
closeness1 <- as.integer(rep("NA",10))
mean1 <- as.integer(rep("NA",10))
sum1 <- as.integer(rep("NA",10))
dt.des <- data.table::data.table(p, time1, closeness1, mean1, sum1)

# Desired output
dsrd.opt <- dplyr::bind_rows(p12, dt.des)

dsrd.opt 
   p time1 closeness1 mean1 sum1
1  1    12         NA  21.5   43
2  1     1         NA  21.5   43
3  1     6         31  21.5   43
4  1     6         12  21.5   43
5  1    17          5  21.5   43
6  2    26         40   NaN    0
7  2    35         18   NaN    0
8  2    39         19   NaN    0
9  2    39         40   NaN    0
10 2    22         NA   NaN    0
11 3    NA         NA    NA   NA
12 3    NA         NA    NA   NA
13 3    NA         NA    NA   NA
14 3    NA         NA    NA   NA
15 3    NA         NA    NA   NA
16 4    NA         NA    NA   NA
17 4    NA         NA    NA   NA
18 4    NA         NA    NA   NA
19 4    NA         NA    NA   NA
20 4    NA         NA    NA   NA
```

## Edit:

It looks like I simplified the above example too much. I basically need to compute the mean of closeness1 based on two separate conditions, once for time1 <= 10 and once for time1 > 10 & time1 <= 21. The respective output should then be saved in two new columns. I have updated the example script accordingly, see below:

```
dt[, c("mean1", "mean2") := .( 
  dplyr::if_else(sum(is.na(.SD[time1,]))==length(.SD[time1,]) | sum(is.na(.SD[closeness1,]))==length(.SD[closeness1,]),
                 as.numeric(NA), .SD[time1 <= 10, mean(closeness1, na.rm=TRUE)]),
  dplyr::if_else(sum(is.na(.SD[time1,]))==length(.SD[time1,]) | sum(is.na(.SD[closeness1,]))==length(.SD[closeness1,]),
                 as.numeric(NA), .SD[time1 > 10 & time1 <= 21, mean(closeness1, na.rm=TRUE)])),
  by = p, .SDcols = c("time1", "closeness1")]
```

### Updated example output

```
dsrd.opt
   p time1 closeness1 mean1 mean2
1  1    12         NA  21.5     5
2  1     1         NA  21.5     5
3  1     6         31  21.5     5
4  1     6         12  21.5     5
5  1    17          5  21.5     5
6  2    26         40   NaN   NaN
7  2    35         18   NaN   NaN
8  2    39         19   NaN   NaN
9  2    39         40   NaN   NaN
10 2    22         NA   NaN   NaN
11 3    NA         NA    NA    NA
12 3    NA         NA    NA    NA
13 3    NA         NA    NA    NA
14 3    NA         NA    NA    NA
15 3    NA         NA    NA    NA
16 4    NA         NA    NA    NA
17 4    NA         NA    NA    NA
18 4    NA         NA    NA    NA
19 4    NA         NA    NA    NA
20 4    NA         NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Tiberius, I can have verbose comments or answers as well, but that first paragraph is *daunting*. I suggest you find a way to reduce the question by removing backstory and providing simple data and simple expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have updated the question by removing some background and some ideas of what might be going on. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: what is your desired output for the `dt` sample dataset?

Comment: I have tried to streamline my question and added script for the desired output

Comment: What is mean1 and sum1, how they are calculated? Your sample desired output just have NAs for those two variables. In other words: what is the condition you're trying to pass to if_else?

Comment: @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta: Thanks. When I run *all* of the above script (including the section "Compute new columns") I only get NAs when column p is 3 or 4. Further clarification I have now added the desired output. Any ideas of how to improve my script above to generate this output with ```data.table```?

Comment: You can use ifelse, eliminating the need for dplyr. But is not clear what you want to calculate with mean1 and sum1. Why you're using sum(is.na... == length...? What you want with sum1 <= 10?

Comment: @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta: Thank you, ifelse vs if_else doesn't change the output: they are interchangeable in this case. What do I want to calculate with mean1? I want to know the average value of closeness1 for all rows of a participant (p) where time1 is smaller than, or equal to, 10 (similar for sum1). As for your second point, I used ```sum(is.na(.SD[time1,]))==length(.SD[time1,])``` to see whether the participant entered any responses or not. In other words, if the number of NAs for a given participant equals the total number of rows, then this participant did not enter any responses.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I would suggest to use a simple left join. I think this is pretty straigthforward and produces the desired result.

```
dt_result <- merge(x = dt
      , y =  dt[time1 <= 10, .(mean1 = mean(closeness1, na.rm = TRUE)
                             , sum1 = sum(closeness1, na.rm = TRUE)), by = list(p)]
      , by.x = "p"
      , by.y = "p"
      , all.x = TRUE
)

> dt_result
    p time1 closeness1 mean1 sum1
 1: 1    12         NA  21.5   43
 2: 1     1         NA  21.5   43
 3: 1     6         31  21.5   43
 4: 1     6         12  21.5   43
 5: 1    17          5  21.5   43
 6: 2    26         40    NA   NA
 7: 2    35         18    NA   NA
 8: 2    39         19    NA   NA
 9: 2    39         40    NA   NA
10: 2    22         NA    NA   NA
11: 3    NA         NA    NA   NA
12: 3    NA         NA    NA   NA
13: 3    NA         NA    NA   NA
14: 3    NA         NA    NA   NA
15: 3    NA         NA    NA   NA
16: 4    NA         NA    NA   NA
17: 4    NA         NA    NA   NA
18: 4    NA         NA    NA   NA
19: 4    NA         NA    NA   NA
20: 4    NA         NA    NA   NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has potential to streamline my script a lot, which would be nice. This made me realize, however, that I simplified my example too much in that I have *several* conditions based on which I need to run the mean. I have updated my post accordingly. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just add another join and update the condition used for filtering.